# Keep an image on foreground and manage collision

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a game app for windows phone.
I'm moving an image over the screen (which is a Map). The user can place a ball where he wants. My question is how can I not allow the ball to be placed on the image?

I think I could check for collision an move the ball out of the rectangle when if necessary.

I have 3 methods for moving my object (`ManipulationStarted`, `OnManipulationDelta`, and `ManipulationOver`).

The one I have a problem with is:

```
private void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    Point A = new Point();
    Point B = new Point();

    e.Handled = true;
    var transform = (sender as UIElement).RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
    A.X = transform.X += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
    A.Y = transform.Y += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
    B.X = savx = transform.X;
    B.Y = savy = transform.Y;

    for (int i = 0; i < cur.lobst.Count(); i++)
    {
        if ((A.X > cur.lobst[i].px
                 && A.X < (cur.lobst[i].px + cur.lobst[i].pw))
             && (A.Y > cur.lobst[i].py
                 && A.Y < (cur.lobst[i].py + cur.lobst[i].ph)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Point inside the rectangle, so inside (under) my object ");
        }

    }
}
```

The message box is never shown. Why is that?

Comment: does lineintrsctrect returns true if there is collison ?

Comment: yes it do, i hae edited my solution, tryin to check if the point is in the rectangle. cause lineinterrect method seems to be useless

Comment: why are you using point you should use intersection of two rects so that it can be precise ...  if you think this way will help you than i can help you further ..

Comment: @Gabson I've edited your post in an attempt to fix some grammar mistakes and make it more clear. Please verify if I understand you correctly and didn't change what you've meant.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, Thats what i meant and its clearer. @Sandeepchauhan i ll try rectangle intersection and update my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this ...

```
public bool Intersects(Rect r1,Rect r2)
{
  r1.Intersect(r2);

  if(r1.IsEmpty)
  {
    return false;
  }
  else 
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

then while checking ...

```
    ismoveallowed = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < cur.lobst.Count(); i++)
    {
        if(Intersects(r1,r2))
        {
           ismovallowed = false;
           break;
        }
    }

    if(ismovealoowed)
    {
       // move the object.
    }
```

i hope this will help you ..